# Exchange Online EWSMaxSubscriptions throttling budget calculation seems to have changed

Tags: office365, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, msdn

We’re monitoring our room’s client calendar to inject the bookings in our software solution.
Each company provides us one service account used to interact with EWS of Office 365

In order to monitor our calendar’s clients mailboxes we use an EWS method : **[PushSubscriptionRequest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/office/aa563599)**

Since last week we’re facing a major issue while sending the **PushSubscriptionRequest** call. The response sent back is :

```
SubscribeResponseMessageType){
         _ResponseClass = "Error"
         MessageText = "You have exceeded the available subscriptions for your account.  Remove unnecessary subscriptions and try your request again."
         ResponseCode = "ErrorExceededSubscriptionCount"
         DescriptiveLinkKey = 0
         MessageXml =
            (MessageXml){
               Value[] =
                  (Value){
                     value = "20"
                     _Name = "PolicyLimit"
                  },
            }
      }
```

It’s happening when the service account tries to subscribe to more than 20 rooms mailboxes . All of our clients with more than 20 rooms are impacted (the biggest ones).

This subscription process was working with absolutely no error since 2 years, it seems **to have change recently** ! (near 26th august)

We’re aware there are EWS throttling policies but as the MSDN Article explains the most important thing to understand is the calculation to achieve this limit
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/exchangedev/2012/04/03/exchange-online-ewsmaxsubscriptions-throttling-budget-calculation-has-been-updated/

> « Starting with service mailbox versions 14.16.0135 and
>   14.15.0057.000, this limit has changed. Now, the charges are counted against the target mailbox rather than the calling account. This way,
>   a service account can create subscriptions against many more than 20
>   mailboxes. One benefit of this change is that you can now design a
>   service application that targets Exchange Online and Exchange
>   on-premises using a similar code base for subscription management. A
>   single service account can now service up to 5000 subscriptions. »

**Why can't we subscribe to more than 20 subscriptions whereas the article indicates 5000 ?**

Above all why the budget calculation has changed? Are we alone to experience this update?

Comment: I think the answer "WHY" that was changed you need to get in contact with Microsoft (try that via your Technical Account Manager) as nobody here would be able to answer that. Normally Microsoft do not change that without further information. You can pay for that and can then join weekly Microsoft meetings which explain what will change why... these meetings are also mostly for the companies which use Exchange Online / 365.

Comment: Hi, yeah i must admit we're kind of surprised so we're trying a lot of knowledge canals. We're so surprised we just want to find developers on Exchange online to  confirm the change as Microsoft doesn't seems to be aware of a change in the calculation method...Anyway thanks for the advice, we'll continue to look for somebody from Microsoft to help.

Comment: The issue with Office 365 is that you need to pass multiple support level until you got one which has the skills to answer that question. From the statement it looks like you reached only level 1 or 2 and due to the fact that there monitoring showed a green mark there was nothing which they can really do here without that you might need to push it and provide more infos.

Comment: We noticed this too, @AdrienSanvoisin.  Have talked to Microsoft.  They say "can't find any evidence of a change in quota", which isn't really an answer at all.  It started August 13ish for us, we noticed around the time you did.

Comment: Hi, after a lot of phone calls let me explain our findings:  
- we weren't correctly declaring impersonation in our webservices calls.  
- Office365 has been migrating since June ot htis year the Exchange  backends to a newer version (Exchange 2016 afaik)  
- Frontends proxies to the backends had been upgraded too  
- Migration of the architecture has been planned on each geographical zone one after each other since then.